# Python: How to solve an ordinary differential equation with integral term in it

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I dont know if this question has been asked before in SO, I will go ahead and post it here, I am attempting to solve a simple system with a PID controller, my system of differential equations are given below. I am basically attempting to code very basic PID algorithm. The structure of my control u depends on both derivative and integral of error term. I dont have any problem with the derivative term, it is the integral term that is creating problem in my code. The problem crops up when I assign s=0 in the beginning 
and use it in my function as described in my code below. Is there a way to bypass it? I tried assigning s and told as global variables, but it didnt solve my problem. In a nutshell what I am doing is- I am adding state x1 every time and multiplying by dt(which is denoted by t-told).

[image]

Kindly help me iron out this issue, PFA my code attached below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('bmh')

t0=0
y0=[0.1,0.2]
kp,kd,ki=2,0.5,0.8
s,told=0,0
def pid(t,Y):
    x1,x2=Y[0],Y[1]
    e=x1-1
    de=x2
    s=(x1+s)
    integral=s*(t-told)
    told=t
    #ie=
    u=kp*e+kd*de+ki*integral
    x1dot=x2
    x2dot=u-5*x1-2*x2
    return[x1dot,x2dot]

solver=ode(pid).set_integrator('dopri5',rtol=1e-6,method='bdf',nsteps=1e5,max_step=1e-3)
solver.set_initial_value(y0,t0)
t1=10
dt=5e-3
sol = [ [yy] for yy in y0 ]
t=[t0]
while solver.successful() and solver.t<t1:
    solver.integrate(solver.t+dt)
    for k in range(2): sol[k].append(solver.y[k]);
    t.append(solver.t)
    print(len(sol[0]))
    print(len(t))
x1=np.array(sol[0])
x2=np.array(sol[1])
e=x1-1
de=x2
u=kp*e+kd*de
for k in range(2):
    if k==0:
        plt.subplot(2,1,k+1)
        plt.plot(t,sol[k],label='x1')
        plt.plot(t,sol[k+1],label='x2')
        plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    else:
        plt.subplot(2,1,k+1)
        plt.plot(t,u)
plt.show()
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? You describe what you try to do but not your exact problem. Maybe include some output from the console?

Comment: The exact problem is-
File "pid.py", line 14, in pid
    s=(x1+s)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment

Comment: The problem is that you use s in the definition but this is the local variable in that function. It will not use the s you defined before that.

Comment: So, how to assign s=0 at the very first instance? I mean how can I set s to be zero when ode takes pid() for the first time?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ode interface, so I don't know if there's a specific solution but you can create a class and have `s` and `told` as properties of this class. Then assign zero to them when creating the class.

Comment: in ode, there is a set_initial_value method available. But when I pass the initial values of y0,t0, it works properly as pid takes two arguments. However when I modified the argument of pid to take y0,t0,s,told and pass the initial values of these in set_initial_value method , it throws up error-
"TypeError: set_initial_value() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)"

Comment: ok, now I changed the pid arguments, and I am using set_f_params(0,0) to assign 0,0. but now it throws-
File "pid.py", line 11, in pid
    x1,x2=Y[0],Y[1]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: This means that Y is a single integer, not an array as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making assumptions on the solver and the time steps that it visits that are not justified. With your hacking of the integral, even if it were mathematically sound (it should look like `integral = integral + e*(t-told)`, which gives an order 1 integration method), you reduce the order of any integration method, probably down to 1, if you are lucky only to order 2.

A mathematically correct method to implement this system is to introduce a third variable `x3` for the integral of `e`, that is, the derivative of `x3` is `e`. That the correct order 1 system has to be of dimension 3 can be read of the fact that (eliminating `e`) your system has 3 differentiation/integration operations. With that your system becomes

```
def pid(t,Y):
    x1, x2, x3 =Y
    e=x1-1
    x1dot = x2
    edot = x1dot
    x3dot = e
    u=kp*e+kd*edot+ki*x3
    x2dot=u-5*x1-2*x2
    return[x1dot, x2dot, x3dot]
```

Note that there are no global dynamic variables necessary, only the constants (which could also be passed as parameters, whatever seems more efficient or readable).

Now you will also need an initial value for `x3`, it was not visible from the system what the integration variable would have to be, your code seems to suggest `0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot LutzL! You saved me a lot of trouble! So, in cases, wherein we have integral expressions in differential equations, it is best to create an extra state.

Comment: Yes. In principle this is the same as resolving a second derivative into two first derivatives by adding an additional state variable.

Comment: Note this doesn't always have to be done. If you use a delay differential equation (DDE) integrator then you can use past values with a quadrature method to approximate the integral to sufficiently high order, though I don't know of a DDE integrator in Python which is sufficiently flexible to do this (the Julia ones can, and MATLAB's can but it's low accuracy). What method is better depends on the problem of course.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to include "s" Variable into the pid function.

'
     def pid(s, t, Y): ...
'

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I can see right now is to create a class with `s` and `told` as properties of this class:

```
class PIDSolver:
    def __init__(self)
        self.t0=0
        self.y0=[0.1,0.2]
        self.kp,self.kd,self.ki=2,0.5,0.8
        self.s,self.told=0,0

    def pid(t,Y):
        x1,x2=Y[0],Y[1]
        e=x1-1
        de=x2
        self.s=(x1+self.s)
        integral=self.s*(t-self.told)
        self.told=t
        #ie=
        u=self.kp*e+self.kd*de+self.ki*integral
        x1dot=x2
        x2dot=u-5*x1-2*x2
        return[x1dot,x2dot]
```

For the first part of your problem. Use `pidsolver = PIDSolver()` in the next part of your solution.

Comment: But how shall I pass this class as an argument to ode method of scipy.integrate?? I created an instance of this class as you have mentioned above i.e pidsolver=PIDSolver(), and then passed this instance in the argument of ode, but I got the error-
When I pass pidsolver, it says -
"_dop.error: failed in processing argument list for call-back fcn."

Comment: You need to pass a function to ode, right? So pass pidsolver.pid as an argument to ode

Comment: I already did that and it throws another error-
File "pid.py", line 17, in pid
    x1,x2=Y[0],Y[1]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: TypeError: unbound method pid() must be called with PIDSolver instance as first argument (got float instance instead)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself by using `set_f_params()` method and passing a list in itz argument. Also I passed a 3rd argument in `pid()` i.e `pid(t,Y,arg)`. And lastly I assigned `s,told=arg[0],arg[1]`.